# AIQL Application Insights query how to exclude weekends

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics, aiql

In some of my reports I'd like to exclude events that happen on weekends as our app is a business application that isn't running on the weekends, yet we do code updates and resulting tests on the weekends that can skew the data.

I've Tried:

`and toint(dayofweek(timestamp)) >= 1 and toint(dayofweek(timestamp)) >= 5 //between Monday and Friday`

But `dayofweek` returns a timespan, not an int, and the `toint` conversion doesn't work (no error is thrown, but result is an empty column.

So how do you exclude weekends? Can you convert `timespan` to `int` another way? Or is there another way to skin this cat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work for me:

```
| parse tostring(dayofweek(timestamp)) with dayOfWeek:int ".00:00:00"
```

Following this line, `dayOfWeek` is an integer holding the day. From there you can slice and dice as needed.

Another option would be to use `substring` - might be faster the `parse`:

```
| project dayOfWeek = toint(substring(tostring(dayofweek(timestamp)), 0, 1))
```

Comment: The`project` option worked...didn't try the `parse` so can't speak to that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing one timestamp by another gives you back their ratio. So, if you divide `dayofweek(timestamp)` by `1d` you'd get the result you need.